# Java: Simple Calculator(data validation)

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Java and OOP at all. 
I'm trying to create a simple calculator using Java Swing.
I want the user to be not able to enter zero after the first one if there is no dot added. 
I've been brainstorming for a lot of time and I couldn't find a solution :( 
Right now if there is only one number entered (different from 0) you can't enter 0. 
Works in every other case.

Here is part of my code:

```
    public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    boolean hasDot = false;
    boolean hasNull = false;

    JButton button0;
    JButton buttonDot;
    JTextArea text;

    public Calculator(){

    //Constructor comes here 
    button0 = new JButton("0");
    buttonDot = new JButton(".");
    text = new JTextArea(1, 20);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == button0) {

            if (text.getText().length() > 0)
                hasNull = true;

            if (hasNull == false) {
                text.append("0");
                hasNull = true;
            }
            if (hasNull == true && hasDot == true) {
                hasNull = false;
                text.append("0");
            }
            if (text.getText().length() > 1 && hasDot == false)
                text.append("0");
        }

        if (e.getSource() == buttonDot && (hasDot == false)
                && text.getText().length() != 0) {
            text.append(".");
            hasDot = true;
            hasNull = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Clarify what you mean; you don't want users to be able to do `100`?

Comment: Not to be able to add 0000 because it should be 0.000 and so on

Comment: Regular expressions is the correct solution. Not sure if it's the easiest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would do the trick. You probably want to avoid having your JFrame be an action listener. It makes the code harder to read. You'll also need to implement the two functions `isNextDigitAfterDecimalPoint` and `getButtonNumber`, but they shouldn't be too hard. These will make your code simpler to reason.

```
public Calculator() {

    //Constructor comes here 
    button0 = new JButton("0");
    button0.addActionListener(mNumberButtonActionListener);
    // other buttons ...

    buttonDot = new JButton(".");
    buttonDot.addActionListener(mDotButtonActionListener);
    text = new JTextArea(1, 20);
}

private ActionListener mNumberButtonActionListener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int numberToAppend = getButtonNumber(e.getSource());
        if (isNextDigitAfterDecimalPoint()) {
            text.append(Integer.toString(numberToAppend))
        } else {
            String currentNumberText = text.getText()
            if (currentNumberText.size() == 0 || !currentNumberText.get(0).equals("0")) {
                text.append(Integer.toString(numberToAppend));
            }
        }
    }
}

private boolean isNextDigitAfterDecimalPoint() { ... }

private int getButtonNumber(JButton button) { ... }

private ActionListener mDotButtonActionListener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (isNextDigitAfterDecimalPoint()) {
            text.append(".");
        }
    }
}
```

One thing you might also like to think about is that your hasNull and hasDot variables are not really necessary. They add extra state to your application. You could get both of these values with methods that interpret the content of the text field. This way you won't have to remember to update them when your text changes.

eg.

```
boolean hasDot() {
    return text.getText().contains(".");
}
```

Comment: The immediate issue I see with this implementation, brought on by op's request, is it's unreasonable to not allow mulitple `.`s in a calculator. If `text` is the entire string, unless there's some mechanism to move the entries elsewhere on `' '` click, you won't be able to do `1.99 + .99`.

Comment: The simplest calculator implementation would not show the whole expression, but rather start a new number in the text field after an operator button was pressed. This would work with my solution. But you are correct to say that this would not work for expressions which need to be parsed. For that, I'd say you would need a more complex data structure to represent the parsed text, which could still have a `lastNumberIsAfterDecimalPoint()` method.